# Input type text declaration in code behind, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, input, textbox

So, this is a textbox:
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

What is the equivalent for an input type=text (it has to be html input with runat=server, i can't use asp:textbox)

Comment: Why can't you use `TextBox`?  Doesn't it render as `<input type="text" runat="server" />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input type = text is referenced as an HTMLControl:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

You can refer to the control using this syntax:

```
string str10 = ((HtmlInputText)e.Item.FindControl("txtYourTextBoxName")).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET TextBox control is the .NET, managed-code equivalent of the `<input type=text />` element, and is rendered to exactly that (unless explicitly specified to render as a password or textarea field).

You can, of course, simply output a primitive element type like that and slap `runat="server"` on it, and reference it in code-behind:

```
<input type="text" id="primitive" runat="server" />
```

But it's referenced in the backend as a generic HTML control, whereby you need to manipulate the `Value` property, as opposed to the convenience properties of 'proper' types, such as the `Text` propert of `TextBox`.

I understand you might have constraints, but the assertion you've made makes nonsense - if you could clarify then maybe we could, too.

Comment: I know it's not the correct way, but i have thousands of inputs created, it's an old project, and i just want to do something very simple. I just want to know how to declare an imput, from the code behind. Is it the same way i create a div? (generic html control, but with 'input' instead of 'div')